# Asterisk does not detect inband DTMF tones

Tags: asterisk

Asterisk 14 (from Packages @ tucny.com)
Connected to Twilio SIP trunk

Asterisk does not detect inband DTMF tones. 
Other ways(INFO, rfc2833) to send DTMF works correctly.
I've played with tone duration and volume without success.
In DTMF debug I can see the asterisk reaction to incoming INFO or rfc2833 events, but nothing happens when inband tone is coming.
Seems like asterisk does not "hear" the line at all.

I couldn't find any information about modules requeried to detect inband DTMF.
Installed modules:
  
  `- asterisk
  - asterisk-odbc
  - asterisk-pjsip
  - asterisk-hep
  - asterisk-sounds-core-en-alaw
  - asterisk-sounds-core-en-ulaw`

Will be very thankfull for any information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of the problem was found.
Pjsip does not support Inband DTMF detection. 
There is information that to detect inband DTMF with pjsip you need to write your own pjsip plugin:
https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/FAQ#dtmf

Answer (score 0):

I do not speak English very well, but I can always try to learn. Sorry for bad interpretations.

DTMF tones need more dependencies as a codec.

Check the codec used on the channel and try changing the dtmfmode to inband. Another item can help is the tones / frequencies in cases of FXO.

In case of codec, check to use alaw.

I hope I have helped or at least give a light.

Hugs!